# How can I decorate my ASP.NET MVC ViewModel property to render as a textarea when using EditorForModel()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I decorate my ASP.NET MVC ViewModel property to render as a textarea when using EditorForModel()

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could decorate the model property with the [`[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute.aspx) attribute:

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyModel());
    }
}
```

View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SomeNs.Models.MyModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <%: Html.EditorForModel() %>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a text area template and then attribute your VM property with a `UIHint("TextArea")` [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.aspx).

Comment: Can you provide a sample or more reference?